# WPF button display only icon

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf application that looks like as follow:
[image]

How can I customize button, that should show only the image without button on the background(hide grey rectangle)?

Comment: Try to search on datatemplates. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Button BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
  <Image Source="Your Image"/>
</Button>
```